# empty space at bottom when tabbar is hidden

Tags: swift, uitableview

In a `TabBar` based app , on a particular `ViewController` TabBar is hidden. on that view there is a table. That table is leaving space at bottom , the height of space is same as of TabBar. How to fix that ??

Comment: Please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using auto layout. Make sure your table view has constraint to bottom layout guide

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve above things by using UIContainerView for tabbar controller